# How do I route a 20 x /24 subnets (secondary) in one shot in Ubuntu 14?

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface

Trying to bind 20 x /24 subnets in Ubuntu 14 Server but I'm stuck here. These are diversified /24 subnets.

I tried the below method via script called addips.sh

```
for i in $(seq 3 254); do echo "auto em1:$i
iface em1:$i inet static
address xxx.xxx.16.$i                                                                               
netmask 255.255.255.0                                                                   
" >> virthosts; done
```

But, I noticed that this happened now:

Each /24 subnet it outputted started off at #1 again instead of 255, 256, 257, etc all the way through consecutively for all 20 x /24 subnets

```
auto em1:1
auto em1:254

Then again...

auto em1:1
...
```

How can I properly change this so it does reset at #1? em1 is the NIC Ethernet port (primary) and only port used too.

I also want to make sure these are permanent, they stick after a server reboot.

Comment: What do you mean by "bind"ing them? A host has secondary *addresses* (not normally subnets, which of course have 256 addresses when they're /24s). And you're two attempts do different things (route them somewhere vs. add a secondary IP)...

Comment: I want to route them in the server as secondary, virtual hosts. See updated post. @derobert

Comment: For routing 20 subnets you need to assign on router (Ubuntu) one ip address from each subnet. You need assign ip addresses 192.168.x.1/24. By example in one subnet 192.168.7.0/24 the router will have ip address 192.168.7.1/24, other host in this subnet must have ip address 192.168.7.x/24 and default route via 192.168.7.1/24.